# Ninject binding resolution by parameter or metadata

Tags: windows-runtime, ninject

Using Ninject 3.x on WinRT, is it possible to query the kernel for bindings only by parameter or metadata i.e.: without specifying type?

Answer (score 3):

No. You have to specify the type.

But you can use any kind of base Interface/class including object.
E.g. Create bindings from `object` to all possible types and get an `object`